# Identify ImageField through introspection

Tags: django, django-models, introspection

OK, I understand that `ImageField` cannot be identified using `get_internal_type()` ([see here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7805)). Applied on a field of type `ImageField` returns `FileField` which is the superclass of `ImageField`.

How can I then distinguish `ImageField` from `FileField` through introspection? I need such a solution in order to apply a generic functionality to arbitrary models.

Comment: Why not `isinstance`?

Comment: Right! That works for me. Thanks Arman.

Comment: You're welcome :)